# String variable appears to reset in nested for loop

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, nested-loops

I have two CSV files.  One has an `image_name` and `genre`, and the other has `image_name` and `image_id`.  I'm essentially trying to combine the two, such that I have one CSV that has `image_name`, `image_id`, and `genre`.  I've attempted to write a script that does the following:

1. For each row in csv a, take `image_name`.
2. Find if `image_name` is in csv b.
3. If `image_name` is in csv b, store the associated `image_id`.
4. Create a new list with `image_id`, `image_name`, and `genre`.
5. Write that list as a row into a new csv.
6. Repeat.

```
import csv
file_name = input("Enter the input csv: ")
f = open(file_name)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

# open image_table
image_table = 'image_table_test.csv'
image = open(image_table)
csv_image = csv.reader(image)

new_file_name = input("What do you want to call the new file? ")
with open(new_file_name, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # for each row in the input csv
    for row in csv_f:
        # if the first item in the row isnt empty
        if row[0]:
            # set star equal to the second item in the row
            genre = row[1]
            # set temp_img_name to the first item in the row
            image_name = row[0]
            # for each row in the image_table
            print(image_name)
            for row_ in csv_image:
                if image_name in row_:
                    # set image_id equal to the first item in the row
                    image_id = row_[0]
                    row_list = [image_id, image_name, genre]
                    writer.writerow(row_list)
```

However, it appears that once the nested for loop is entered, the image_name resets to the original value.  Why is this happening?  What am I missing and/or what do I need to do to make this process work correctly?

UPDATE:

When the following code runs:

```
with open(new_file_name, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # for each row in the input csv
    for row in csv_f:
        # if the first item in the row isnt empty
        if row[0]:
            # set star equal to the second item in the row
            genre = row[1]
            # set temp_img_name to the first item in the row
            image_name = row[0]
            # for each row in the image_table
            print(image_name)
            for row_ in csv_image:
                if image_name in row_:
                    # set image_id equal to the first item in the row
                    image_id = row_[0]
                    row_list = [image_id, image_name, genre]
                    writer.writerow(row_list)
```

I get this output (which is expected):

```
image_name
248_COMEDY_20130523_112147.jpg
248_COMEDY_20130523_112147.jpg
```

However, when I run this version:

```
with open(new_file_name, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # for each row in the input csv
    for row in csv_f:
        # if the first item in the row isnt empty
        if row[0]:
            # set star equal to the second item in the row
            genre = row[1]
            # set temp_img_name to the first item in the row
            image_name = row[0]
            # for each row in the image_table
            for row_ in csv_image:
                print(image_name)
                if image_name in row_:
                    # set image_id equal to the first item in the row
                    image_id = row_[0]
                    row_list = [image_id, image_name, genre]
                    writer.writerow(row_list)
```

I get this output (which is unexpected):

```
image_name
image_name
image_name
```

Note that the only difference is when the `print(image_name)` is called.

Comment: You are deleting and re-opening `new_file_name` each time you want to record a row because you use the `w` mode. You should open the file only once at the top of your script and only call `.writerow()` within the loop.

Comment: ahh thank you, missed that.  let me play around now and see if i can get it to work!

Comment: i've moved the file open out of the for loop, but appear to still be running into the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion comes from how iterators (the CSV `reader` object is an iterator) work in Python. You can only consume those once. So what is happening here the first time:

```
for row_ in csv_image:
    print(image_name)
```

You are executing the loop 3 times (because there are 3 rows in `csv_image`) and print the same value 3 times.

When you try to execute the same `for` loop a second time (because the outer loop is now in row #2) it doesn't execute at all, because `csv_image` has already been consumed. That's why you don't see the result of your `print` statements *inside* the inner loop.

What you want to do is to open the `csv_image` every time you want to process it:

```
with open(image_file_name, 'r', newline='') as image_file:
    csv_image = csv.reader(image_file)
    for row_ in csv_image:
        ...
```

That being said, this is a horribly inefficient algorithm as you will read from the same file `n` times where `n` is the number of rows in `csv_f`. I suggest you to read `csv_image` and store the rows in a `list` or a `dict`, then process `csv_f` and compare rows with the in-memory list/dict.

Comment: thanks, this is a very helpful explanation.  appreciate the call-out on efficiency as well!  i will take this and re-implement tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting and opening the file every time in the inner loop.
This will work:

```
with open(new_file_name, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in csv_f:
        # if the first item in the row isnt empty
        if row[0]:
            # set genre equal to the second item in the row
            genre = row[1]
            # set image_name to the first item in the row
            image_name = row[0]
            # for each row in the image_table
            for row_ in csv_image:
                if image_name in row_:
                    # set image_id equal to the first item in the row
                    image_id = row_[0]
                    row_list = [image_id, image_name, genre]
                    writer.writerow(row_list)
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to fix the issue.  if i print image_name right before the second for loop, the value is correct.  if i print image_name right after the second for loop begins, the value appears to be continually resetting to the first value.

Comment: @user2163853 There is nothing in this code that can cause the behaviour you describe. Please update your question with the `print` statements you mentioned and also post a sample output. You might have other code that you are not showing us that might cause the issue.

Comment: @selcuk - i've updated the original post to include the two version and output.  thanks for your help.